# Suppressing warnings in Xcode 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode7, pragma

Until now in Xcode 6 I was able to suppress warnings for some external libraries by using pragma directives, like this:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdocumentation"
#import "SwiftToObjectiveC-Swift.h"
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

Since I updated my project to Xcode 7 this directives seem to do nothing, I get all the documentation warnings that are on SwiftToObjectiveC-Swift.h.
Anyone has an idea what it could be the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Is that the only place that includes the header file?

Comment: Yes, that was my first thought also.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to suppress all warnings in Xcode 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33111048/how-to-suppress-all-warnings-in-xcode-7)