# How to suppress or ignore all warnings in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, warnings, compiler-warnings

Does anyone know how to suppress all warnings in Xcode 7? I've tried pragmas and compiler flags... nothing works

Comment: Really really bad idea. Warnings are your friend, letting you know when you are gettig close to trouble. Thank them by correcting the code (it is a bad code problem after all).

Comment: Either correct the problem as @zaph suggests, or judiciously make suppressions instead of just using a big hammer to turn all of them off. I would strongly suggest you never suppress a security warning.

Comment: Yes I do plan on fixing all warnings, but while I'm on a train of thought I don't want to see them at all.

Comment: A suit just spoke.  Ah nice suit, just joking, [Vint Cerf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vint_Cerf#/media/File:Vint_Cerf_-_2010.jpg) wears a mean suit and he's “Father of the Internet”.

Comment: Thanks! It gets me from A to B :D

Comment: A good reason to have this ability is when you import an Xcode project which is a framework, and its old code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, **it's a really bad idea: warnings exist for a reason**, you really should check each of them.

But... you want suppress every warning or just a few types there's a way, check these easy steps and turn off all or just what you need:

**1)** search for "show warning" in your **build settings**

[image]

**2)** under **build settings** search for **Apple LLVM 7.0 - Warnings - All languages**

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work! I can still see multiple warnings.. I'm beginning to think there is not a way to suppress all warnings!

Comment: What type of warnings did you get? Because these settings work but maybe you have warning not relate to languages or interface builder.

Comment: I selected 'No' for deprecated functions for instance, and it still gives me warnings.