# "Fixed leading and trailing constraints may cause clipping" bug?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, constraints, xcode9

There's [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45122691/3539651) here that addresses a similar issue, but in that case Xcode's behavior is correct, just annoying.

In my case, however, I think it's actually a bug:

[image: example]

That label can have an unlimited number of lines, so it'll never be clipped, the text will just break.

It works fine with every localization:

[image: example2]

I want the label to be centered and I want the text to be at least 20 pixels away from the margins, so I set fixed constraints for the leading and trailing. Xcode wants me to change one of them to a "greater than or equal" constraint, but in that case the text won't be perfectly centered (I tried).

All I want is centered text that won't be too close to the margins, but now I can't accomplish that without triggering that warning.

Any ideas on how to fix this? Is it really a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

---

**Edit:** Here's a screenshot showing the error. The constraints aren't directly in a view controller, but in a subview that I use as the backgroun for a table view. If I remove those constraints the warning goes away; if I add them back it shows up again. I tried this in a new project and couldn't reproduce it, I have no idea why it's happening here.

[image: example3]

**Edit:**

Here's another example. When the right constraint is set to "greater than or equal" all's well:

[image: example4]

As soon as I set it to "equal", boom:

[image: example5]

Comment: can you post the warning you´re receiving? and which xcode are you ussing?

Comment: @ReinierMelian Xcode 9; I set it as a tag but forgot to mention in the text. The warning is the one in the title. The complete text says "fixed leading and trailing constraints may cause clipping, one of them should have a constant ≥ standard space". Thanks. :)

Comment: @ReinierMelian If I set one of the constraints to "greater than or equal" the warning goes away, but the text won't be centered on the view.

Comment: If you are convinced you have a bug (and especially if you have an example of the bug) then you should report it to Apple: https://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: ok @dbmrq using Xcode 8.3.2 this warning is not present, I don't have Xcode 9 yet

Comment: @RoboticCat Yeah, I was just hoping someone would confirm it's actually a bug and maybe offer a workaround.

Comment: @ReinierMelian Yes, it's new in Xcode 9.

Comment: You might try setting one width ≥ and the other ≤ to suppress this warning. Use the same value for each. Haven't found a better solution yet...

Comment: @atlex2 I did try that before asking the question, but it wouldn't work properly, the text would often be out of alignment when running the app. With the latest Xcode updates the problem seems to have disappeared for me though. I'm not sure if it's actually fixed, sometimes weird stuff still shows up, but those warnings that I couldn't get rid of are now gone and the new one's are usually easy to fix. ‍♂️

Answer (score 6):

If you're still looking for an answer, in your particular case, try setting a proportional width on your label and center horizontally in the view controller's view.

Clear all your constraints on the label, right-click drag from the label to the `Background View` and select `Equal Widths`, `Center Horizontally in Container`, and `Center Vertically in Container` from the popup menu.

Now since you said you wanted 20px margin both to the left and right of your label, edit the `Multiplier` on the equal width constraint and set it to `widthOfBackgroundView - 40)/widthOfBackgroundView`.

So let's say the width of your background view is `414`, the multiplier is supposed to be `374/414`.

The reason for the `width minus 40` multiplier is it covers 20px on either sides of the label. This should make your warning go away and layout the label the way you're expecting it to be.

I had the same issue and was able to fix the warnings this way. Hope this helps!

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please don't ping in answers.  Use comments for that.  The author of the question will see your answer anyway.

Comment: The warnings seem to have disappeared out of the blue, but that’s a good idea, I’ll keep it in mind if it happens again. :)

Answer (score 3):

Some problem here, introduced with the final version of Xcode 9. Seems that the bug is related to the language direction: for some reason Interface Builder doesn't understand quite well the autolayout for the default language direction conditions.

As suggested by [Repose](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4577610/repose) on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45764271/387507) you should try to invalidate the use of language direction for at least one of the failing constraints (ie. trailing). This approach solved my warnings.

Answer (score 2):

Checked in Xcode 9GM (Version 9.0 (9A235)), it works correctly

[image: Xcode screenshot]

Remove the constraints and add them manually.

Comment: How odd, I just tried it on a new project and it works fine, but for some reason it's still happening on the project I was working before, even if I remove the constraints and add them back. :/

Comment: @dbmrq Please make a screenshot with the rest of the view of this VC and their constraints

Comment: I edited my question with another screenshot. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try to recreate the background view