# How to fix "Fixed width constraints may cause clipping" warning in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I have a button that is 50x50 in size, and I want it to be at the bottom right corner

[image]

And I've set it up using these constraints

[image]

But I get this warning, how to fix?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are showing a long text in the button, it will *clip* it. One way to silence the warning is setting the constraint to "greater than or equal". Select the constraint, click "Edit", then select ">=" next to "Constant". Or double click it (or select it in the storyboard pane) and select "greater than or equal" at the "relation" row.

Check out @shades' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45765936/6603599) for more details.