# Xcode Warning saying UIButton may be clipped

Tags: xcode, uibutton, autolayout, xcode9

[image: screenshot]

I am migrating this to Xcode 9.

The button is clearly not going to be clipped, why is it giving me this warning?

Comment: Thank you @LeoDabus. That makes sense, but I had already tried recreating my constraints like 5 times.

Comment: Is this possibly the new localization warnings in Xcode 9? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45039846/xcode-9-localization-issue-warning-storyboard

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45122691/xcode-9-fixed-width-constraints-may-cause-clipping-and-other-localization-wa

Answer (score 0):

Buttons with text and a fixed width **can** easily be clipped.

Whenever you decide to modify the text through code or decide to use Dynamic Type for the button's text, this can be a valid issue.

Generally speaking, it's a bad idea to set a fixed width to something that can vary.