# Getting empty Localization Issue warning message for storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm using Xcode version 9.2, I have tried to delete the derived data but still getting empty warning message for storybard as show in pic below. I cannot know what is the problem if the warning is empty, any idea how to fix this?
[image]

> **Update**
>
> *I have solve the warning by change the constraint from this* [image]
>
> 1. Left constraint "Greater Than or Equal" with first item as TextView.Leading and second item as Superview.Leading.Margin
> 2. Right constraint "Greater Than or Equal" with first item as Superview.Trailing.Margin and second item as TextView.Trailing
>
> *to this by just reverse first and second item for "2"*
>
> [image]
>
> 1. Left constraint "Greater Than or Equal" with first item as TextView.Leading and second item as Superview.Leading.Margin
> 2. Right constraint "Less Than or Equal" with first item as TextView.Trailing and second item as Superview.Trailing.Margin
>
> How ever I'm not sure why this will cause the empty warning message

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45039846/xcode-9-localization-issue-warning-storyboard/45040394

Comment: It's not because of derived data and cleaning won't help.

Comment: @MaulikBhuptani The solution link that you provided is warning message which is not Empty (Fixed width constraints may causes....)

Comment: Have you clicked on that yellow triangle button and any popup opens up?

Comment: I've edit the screenshot, the popup thing seem show nothing

Comment: Added an answer which should help you.

Answer (score 1):

Silence the fixed-width warnings by changing the width of the object spacings from fixed width to greater than or equal or less than or equal.

This can be done by selecting the object in interface builder, going to the size inspector and changing it there:

[image]

Or, select the constraint from the document outline, go to size inspector, and change it there:

Fixed leading and trailing constraints with a center constraint may cause clipping

[image]

This will certainly solve all your localization issues :: [Xcode 9 - Localization Issue Warning Storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45122691/xcode-9-fixed-width-constraints-may-cause-clipping-and-other-localization-wa/45764271#45764271)

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:

- Move the storyboard from the Base.lproj folder up one level via
  Finder
- Delete the storyboard reference from your project via Xcode
- Drag and drop (or otherwise re-add) the storyboard to your project
- Verify using the File Inspector that the storyboard no longer has
  base localization

**It should work!!**